# Pass Jade model variable to a view script function parameter

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to pass a Jade model variable as a parameter to a JavaScript function.

I'm reading the `socketUrl` variable from config and passing it to the view:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var socketUrl = config.get("socketUrl");
    res.render("index", {title: "Ticker", socketUrl: socketUrl});
});
```

Now I wont to use it in a view script `ticker.initialize(socketUrl)`:

```
html
  head
    script(src="js/socket.io-1.4.5.js")
    script(src="js/ticker.js")
    script.
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            ticker.initialize(socketUrl);
        });
```

The browser cannot read `socketUrl` in that way. How to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but only with strings:

```
script.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        ticker.initialize("#{socketUrl}");
    });
```

If it's an object try `!{socketUrl}`

Comment: Thank you. It works. I have tried with `!{socketUrl}` :(

Comment: It should be `ticker.initialize("#{socketUrl}");`.